# Сложные случаи согласования

Tags: грамматика, согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, местоимения какого рода следует выбирать в подобных случаях:

*Неуверенность – это качество, выражающее сомнение, нерешительность, недоверие к себе и окружающим. (Она/Оно) оказывает негативное влияние на человеческую жизнь...*

Местоимение, начинающее второе предложение, требуется согласовывать со словом "неуверенность" и, соответственно, сделать выбор в пользу "она" или с "качество" и подобрать местоимение "оно"?

Извиняюсь за не совсем удачную формулировку вопроса, так как даже не приходит в голову, каким правилом следует руководствоваться в данном примере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процитирую Розенталя:

> **1. Местоимение 3-го лица (*он, она, оно, они*)** обычно заменяет ближайшее к нему предшествующее существительное в форме того же рода и числа. Однако эта связь местоимения с существительным определяется иногда смыслом, а не формально порядком слов, например: ***Туристы** побывали во многих городах страны: **они** интересовались прежде всего местными историческими достопримечательностями* (не вызывает сомнений, что местоимение **они** относится к более отдаленному существительному **туристы**, а не к ближе стоящему *городах*).
>
> Возможность соотнесения местоимения с разными словами в предшествующем тексте может служить источником неясности или двусмысленности, например: ***Сестра** поступила в артистическую труппу, **она** скоро уезжает на гастроли* (кто уезжает — сестра или труппа?). В этих случаях необходима правка; ср.:
> а) ***Сестра** поступила в артистическую труппу **и скоро уезжает на гастроли***;
> б) ***Сестра поступила в** артистическую труппу, которая скоро уезжает на гастроли; Мать Оли, когда она заболела, стала очень нервной* (кто заболел – мать или Оля?); *Внесены добавления в оба текста; они нуждаются в некоторых уточнениях* (нуждаются в уточнениях тексты или добавления?).

Я думаю, что правильно использовать местоимение "оно":
*Неуверенность — это **качество**, выражающее сомнение, нерешительность, недоверие к себе и окружающим. **Оно** оказывает негативное влияние на человеческую жизнь...*
[Без причастного оборота: Неуверенность — это качество <...>. Оно оказывает...]

[§169. Личные местоимения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта правильные: если использовать ‟она”, то воспринимающий текст будет относить это местоимение к ‟неуверенность”; если использовать ‟оно”, то воспринимающий текст будет относить это слово к ‟качество”.